# Rust - Multiple Calls to Iterator Methods

Tags: rust, iterator

I have this following rust code:

```
fn tokenize(line: &str) -> Vec<&str> {
    let mut tokens = Vec::new();
    let mut chars = line.char_indices();
    for (i, c) in chars {
        match c {
            '"' => {
                if let Some(pos) = chars.position(|(_, x)| x == '"') {
                    tokens.push(&line[i..=i+pos]);
                } else {
                    // Not a complete string
                }
            }
            // Other options...
        }
    }
    tokens
}
```

I am trying to elegantly extract a string surrounded by double quotes from the line, but since `chars.position` takes a mutable reference and `chars` is moved into the for loop, I get a compilation error - "value borrowed after move". The compiler suggests borrowing `chars` in the for loop but this doesn't work because an immutable reference is not an iterator (and a mutable one would cause the original problem where I can't borrow mutably again for `position`).

I feel like there should be a simple solution to this.
Is there an idiomatic way to do this or do I need to regress to appending characters one by one?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because a `for` loop will take ownership of `chars` (because it calls [`.into_iter()`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/rust-by-example/flow_control/for.html#for-and-iterators) on it) you can instead manually iterate through `chars` using a [`while`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/rust-by-example/flow_control/while_let.html) loop:

```rust
fn tokenize(line: &str) -> Vec<&str> {
    let mut tokens = Vec::new();
    let mut chars = line.char_indices();
    while let Some((i, c)) = chars.next() {
        match c {
            '"' => {
                if let Some(pos) = chars.position(|(_, x)| x == '"') {
                    tokens.push(&line[i..=i+pos]);
                } else {
                    // Not a complete string
                }
            }
            // Other options...
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It works if you just desugar the for-loop:

```
fn tokenize(line: &str) -> Vec<&str> {
    let mut tokens = Vec::new();
    let mut chars = line.char_indices();
    while let Some((i, c)) = chars.next() {
        match c {
            '"' => {
                if let Some(pos) = chars.position(|(_, x)| x == '"') {
                    tokens.push(&line[i..=i+pos]);
                } else {
                    // Not a complete string
                }
            },
            _ => {},
        }
    }
    tokens
}
```

The normal for-loop prevents additional modification of the iterator because this usually leads to surprising and hard-to-read code. Doing it as a while-loop has no such protection.

If all you want to do is find quoted strings, I would not, however, go with an iterator at all here.

```
fn tokenize(line: &str) -> Vec<&str> {
    let mut tokens = Vec::new();
    let mut line = line;
    while let Some(pos) = line.find('"') {
        line = &line[(pos+1)..];
        if let Some(end) = line.find('"') {
            tokens.push(&line[..end]);
            line = &line[(end+1)..];
        } else {
            // Not a complete string
        }
    }
    tokens
}
```

Comment: Thanks! I do other things as well, not just find quoted strings - that was just what caused the problem.